# Should isDaylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate for Pacific/Auckland and 14-Jan-2014 be true or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get add DST offset to a date depending on the daylight status in a particular time zone.

My problem is that

```
[timeZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:date]
```

always returns true for timeZone "Auckland/NewZealand" and date "01-Jan-2014". This should be false as daylight saving for Auckland start in April and ends in September.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using (including how you get the time zone and date)? Please also include log output of time zone, date and the return value from isDaylights...

Comment: Btw, I'm assuming that your code is supposed to use `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:` instead of `isDaylightSavingTimeZone:` (which doesn't exist and seems like a typo)

Comment: The daylight saving data is stored in the iOS. I am not sure if it gets updated on regular basis. Consider an example, in a country A the daylight saving time starts from April and Ends in August. If the government of that country A decides to change it from April to June, it will not get updated in the iOS. So, if you need precision and update, use some third party API to determine the daylight saving time. http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=22

Comment: Yes David...It was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=22,
daylight saving time *starts* in September and *ends* in April in Auckland
(which makes sense as it is on the southern hemisphere).

So your result is correct: "01-Jan-2014" is during the summer and the daylight saving
time is active.

Note that (as David commented above), the correct call is

```
[timeZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:date]
```

Comment: Haha! I looked at that data and didn't realize that it lists the month it ends first and then then month that it starts after.

Comment: Eeeee!! Sorry for my wrong information but I have a calendar in my application. The system calendar and application calendar for minneapolis matches according to the DST but according to what you are saying my system calendar do not show changes according to DST in Auckland.

Comment: @user3202263: Sorry, I do not understand. The DST in Auckland is from September to April, so there *is* DST in January. - And now your code uses `daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:`? That would return `3600` for your date.  Did you mean `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:`?

Comment: Sorry Martin for the confusion. My actual problem is that when my time zone is minneapolis my system calendar shifts events according  to minneapolis DST but in case of Auckland it is not shifting according to DST in Auckland.

Comment: @user3202263: There is probably more information needed to solve *that* problem. Perhaps you can reduce the problem to a small reproducible example and post the code (with NSLogs for all the time zones, dates etc) in a new question.